LINQPad 8 Dump Property Order different that LINQPad 5
In LINQPad 5 with Linq-to-Sql DataContext, if I dump out a table.
Users.Take( 5 ).Dump();

The results pane has properties in order they were defined in the .dbml file, and thus in the order they were placed in the generated C# class.
In LINQPad 8 with EF Core DbContext objects, if I dump out the same table, the properties are always dumped in alphabetical order vs the order of property declaration in the scaffolded class.
Is there a way to make it dump based on order of declaration?
I saw post about Change order of dump properties which I could maybe implement, but would rather just get a default behavior of order properties appear in class.
Using reflection, if I do typeof( KAT.Camelot.DbContexts.Evolution.AWS.User ).GetProperties().Dump(); the order of the properties listed is in order of declaration.
Update: Screenshot of output and code.

Here is scaffolded class:
[Table("User")]
[Index("AuthID", "GroupKey", Name = "UniqueAuthID", IsUnique = true)]
[Index("Email", "GroupKey", Name = "UniqueEmail", IsUnique = true)]
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column("User_id")]
    public int Key { get; set; }

    
    /// <summary>
    /// Foreign Key to Group
    /// </summary>
    [Column("User_Group_id")]
    public int? GroupKey { get; set; }

    [Column("User_Authenticate_id")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? AuthID { get; set; }

    [Column("User_Register_id")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? RegisterID { get; set; }

    [Column("User_Profile", TypeName = "text")]
    public string? Profile { get; set; }

    [Column("User_Email")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? Email { get; set; }

    [Column("User_Pin")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? Pin { get; set; }

    [Column("User_Timeout", TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? Timeout { get; set; }

    [Column("Create_Date", TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Column("Mod_Date", TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }

    
    /// <summary>
    /// Date user last logged onto the system.
    /// </summary>
    [Column("User_LastOn", TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
    public DateTime? LastOnDate { get; set; }

    
    /// <summary>
    /// Whether or not the user can log onto the system.
    /// </summary>
    [Column("User_Active")]
    public bool? Active { get; set; }

    [Column("userPasswordExpire", TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
    public DateTime? PasswordExpire { get; set; }

    [Column("uFailureCount")]
    public int? FailureCount { get; set; }

    [Column("userAdmin")]
    public bool? Admin { get; set; }

    
    /// <summary>
    /// The &apos;AuthID&apos; the admin will use to sign in with (if not same as real auth id - use when people are both participants and admins)
    /// </summary>
    [Column("uAdminAuthID")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? AdminAuthID { get; set; }

    [Column("User_Token")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? Token { get; set; }

    
    /// <summary>
    /// If this matches cookie in users browser then they can autologon.
    /// </summary>
    [Column("User_AutoLogon")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? AutoLogon { get; set; }

    [Column("uStayLoggedIn")]
    public bool? StayLoggedIn { get; set; }

    [Column("uProcessed")]
    public bool? Processed { get; set; }

    [Column("uIVRPin")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? IVRPin { get; set; }

    [Column("uEmailReset")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? EmailReset { get; set; }

    [Column("uSingleSignOnID")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? SingleSignOnID { get; set; }

    [Column("uAuthenticatorKey")]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? AuthenticatorKey { get; set; }

    [Column("uMobileNumber")]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Column("uAuthenticatorGrace")]
    public int? AuthenticatorGrace { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupKey")]
    [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public virtual Group? Group { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Preference> Preferences { get; set; } = new List<Preference>();
}


I am not seeing this behavior, using the Demo (SQLite) database that ships with LINQPad. Albums.Take(5) shows the same order of properties that typeof(Album).GetProperties() shows. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

I'm fairly sure that this is not a LinqPad thing but actually a .NET Debug vs. Release thing. What happens if you toggle Debug-mode in LinqPad?

No repro for me, btw (though I'm not using Linq-to-SQL, just a normal class object): https://imgur.com/a/nBn4sfG

Are you sure Preferences/Results/Column ordering is set to ordinal?

@sgmoore Nope :)  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.
